# How to get last(256th) column and second row in google spreadsheet using Range

Tags: google-sheets-api

How to get last(256th) column and second row in google spreadsheet using Range?We can get 2nd column and second row  using Range "A2:B2".How to do same for 256th column

Answer (score 1):

Whatever that columns name is, you can specify using the A1 Notation: Here are the samples from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation):

> - Sheet1!A1:B2 refers to the first two cells in the top two rows of
> - Sheet1. Sheet1!A:A refers to all the cells in the first column of
> - Sheet1. Sheet1!1:2 refers to the all the cells in the first two rows
>     of Sheet1.
> - Sheet1!A5:A refers to all the cells of the first column of
> - Sheet 1, from row 5 onward. A1:B2 refers to the first two cells in the
>     top two rows of the first visible sheet.
> - Sheet1 refers to all the
>     cells in Sheet1.

However, deducing from your use case, I think you only want to fetch a single cell somewhere in column 256. You can use this format:

```
sheetName!AA2
```

where AA is the name of the colum and 2 is the row number.